# Update values of only selected GridItem SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, xcode15, ios17, lazyvgrid

I activate a `.contextMenu` by selecting a `GridItem` in a `LazyVGrid`. Then change a `Bool` value in just that selected `GridItem` to update its contents.

My issue is after tapping the Button in the `.contextMenu` and changing the Bool. The changes are shown in all GridItem not just selected.

How. to just reflect changes in selected GridItem?

```
import SwiftUI
    
    struct GridItemView: View {
        
        var id : Int
        @Binding var isRed : Bool
        
        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Text("Hello")
                Image(systemName: "globe.europe.africa")
            }
            .foregroundStyle(isRed ? .red : .black)
            .padding()
            .border(.black)
        }
    }
```

---

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    let gridLayout = Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 0), count: 4)
    let numberOfGridItems = 1092
    
    @State private var isRed : Bool = false
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView(.vertical) {
                LazyVGrid(columns: gridLayout){
                    ForEach(0..<numberOfGridItems, id: \.self){ gridItemIndex in
                       let myGridItem = GridItemView(id: gridItemIndex, isRed: $isRed)
                        myGridItem.contextMenu{
                            Button(action: {
                                myGridItem.isRed.toggle()
                            },
                                   label: {
                                Label("Toggle isRed for gridItemIndex \(myGridItem.id)", systemImage: "paintbrush.fill")
                                
                            })
                        }
                        
                    }
                }.scrollTargetLayout()
            }.scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned)
        }
    }
}
```

Outcome Vs Expected
[image: Outcome and Expected Outcome]

**Sorry 1st image should have shown all items as Red

Comment: Should it be possible for multiple items to be red simultaneously? Or, when you turn an item red, should any other red item become black again?

Comment: `@State private var isRed : Bool = false`, this is one property but you have 1092 cells that all share this single property. What exactly is your data source here?

Comment: @robmayoff Only the items selected should turn red (or back to black if tapped again). The value of the bool will be stored in a database so on further loads the items set to red will be loaded up as.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson my data source will either be swiftData or CoreData. For now in testing the data source is simply the ForEach Loop. Migrating over from Storyboards to be fully SwiftUI

Comment: Ah should the @State be inside the ForEach Loop so to create one for each iteration ?

Comment: No you can't have a @State property declared inside the ForEach (unless it's in a sub-view) but if you are going to use SwiftData/Core Data then I assume you will have an army of objects and that each has this Bool property that you will use in the grid cells.

Comment: army == array :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution from [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65184473/1045446)

rather than having a `@Binding` to a Bool which was setting the Bool value of all my GridItems not just those which were selected. I instead added the `gridItemIndex` to an Array  `@State private var isSelected : [Int] = []` and moved the`.contextMenu` (Though have changed to an `overlay`) to perform the actions from being created inside the `ForEach` where I create my `LazyVGrid` to the `GridItemView` itself and handle the changes there.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let gridLayout = Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 0), count: 3)
    let numberOfGridItems = 9//1092
    
    
    @State private var isSelected : [Int] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView(.vertical) {
                LazyVGrid(columns: gridLayout){
                    ForEach(0..<numberOfGridItems, id: \.self){ gridItemIndex in
                        GridItemView(gridItemViewID: gridItemIndex, isSelectedGridItems: $isSelected)
                
                    }
                }.scrollTargetLayout()
            }.scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned)
        }
    }
}




    struct GridItemView: View {
    
   // renamed from var id : Int
      let gridItemViewID : Int

     @Binding var isSelectedGridItems : [Int]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe.europe.africa")
                }
        .foregroundStyle(isSelectedGridItems.contains(gridItemViewID) ? .red : .black)
        .padding()
        .border(.black)
        //changed from .contextMenu to .overlay
        .overlay(alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
            Menu {
                Button("Change to Red", action: {
                    if isSelectedGridItems.contains(gridItemViewID) {
                        isSelectedGridItems.removeAll {
                            return $0 == gridItemViewID
                        }
                       
                    }
                    else{
                        isSelectedGridItems.append(gridItemViewID)
                    }
                })
               
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "ellipsis.circle.fill")
                    .padding(2)
            }.foregroundStyle(.black)

        }
    }
}
```